# Discovering unused tables in a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I was assigned the task of going through the tables in our database and writing a query to figure out which tables are not used anymore by any of our procedures.

Here are some starting points I have to try and figure out how to write the query.

System tables to query:

- `sys.tables` – contains all tables. The function `schema_name()` can be used to translate the `schema_id` column to that actual name.
- `sys.procedures` – contains all procedures. Function `schema_name()` can be used here also.
- `sys.sql_modules` – contains the actual procedure code in the column `definition`. This table joins to `sys.procedures` using the column `object_id`. You can query the definition column for the existence of tables using the like predicate and wildcards for example: `where definition not like '%<schema_name.table_name>%'`

Thanks!

```
select 
    schema_name(schema_id), name
from 
    sys.tables
where 
    schema_name(schema_id) in ('Final', 'Stage', 'Utils', 'TRX', 'Reporting')
order by 
    schema_name(schema_id)
```

Here is a simple query I wrote that gets me a list of all our tables. I've put this list into a temp table and my goal is to loop through that temp table i create passing in the current table to the query of the procedures/`sql_module` tables.

From that list I can individually take each table and query it against the procedures/sql_modules to see if it is used in any of our procedures.

```
select
    schema_name(schema_id), name
from 
    sys.procedures p
inner join 
    sys.sql_modules sm on p.object_id = sm.object_id
where 
    sm.definition like '%Final.NameOfTabletImSearching%'
```

This query will return a list of procedures that use the table I'm searching, or will return blank if no procedures return the table, but what I am trying to do is write a query that can give me a list of tables that are not used at all using the temp table I passed in.

Comment: Do you enforce strict schema prefix usage in all your procedures? Do different schemas share table names? Do all users have the same default schema?

Comment: i think it's better to be safe than sorry, i'd just search for table names without schemas

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

- A wildcard search through the definitions stored in sys.sql_modules is going to miss some use cases. Using your example, what if the procedure text used `[Final].[NameOfTabletImSearching]`? Your query would miss that entirely.
- What if the table is referenced indirectly via a view?

For these cases, I'd check sys.sql_expression_dependencies. Like so:

```sql
select schema_name(t.schema_id), t.name
from sys.tables as t
where schema_name(t.schema_id) in ('Final', 'Stage', 'Utils', 'TRX', 'Reporting')
and not exists (
    select 1
    from sys.sql_expression_dependencies as d
    where d.referenced_id = t.object_id
)
order by schema_name(t.schema_id);
```

Note: there's no need to loop through a list of tables here. Generally speaking, iterating a list in SQL is a "code smell" that should incite pause.

- What if the table is referenced indirectly via a synonym?

I leave it as an exercise to adapt the query above to accommodate synonyms as well. You can either add it as a predicate to that query (for an all-in-one query) or run it separately.

Lastly, checking that there are no references in stored procedures/functions is necessary but not sufficient if the goal is to eventually get rid of these tables. That is, there could be processes accessing the tables directly. I've used [SQL Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) in similar cases for tables that I've suspected of being unused over a period of time prior to renaming and ultimately dropping them.

Comment: Docs say *`referenced_id` : The value of this column is always NULL for cross-server and cross-database references. NULL for references within the database if the ID cannot be determined. For non-schema-bound references, the ID cannot be resolved in the following cases: - The referenced entity does not exist in the database. - The schema of the referenced entity depends on the schema of the caller and is resolved at run time. In this case, is_caller_dependent is set to 1.* so even that isn't very reliable if the code doesn't strictly use two-part naming. Never mind dynamic SQL etc.

Comment: See earlier comments in re: "necessary but not sufficient".